# {NativeScript} SideDrawer error "Module 'ui/drawer-content' not found for element 'DrawerContent'"

Tags: android, nativescript

NativeScript beginner, I have been searching all over the web but since there seemed to have many iterations/changed in the base code over the last months, the examples I found on the web were pretty inconsistent.

So here goes, I am trying to implement a simple SideDrawer from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" but fail miserably.

Several points to note:

- in the *main-page.ts* file, I can not seem to access the "id" attribute of the sidedrawer (always return undefined)
- on run (on Android, did not try iOS yet), I got the following error: "Module 'ui/drawer-content' not found for element 'DrawerContent'"

Below are my files+code:

**package.json**

```
{
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.githubreader",
        "tns-ios": {
            "version": "1.7.0"
        },
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "1.7.1"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "github-api": "^0.11.2",
        "lodash": "^4.10.0",
        "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.0.1",
        "tns-core-modules": "1.7.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.9"
    }
}
```

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
    xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
    loaded="loaded" 
    navigatingTo="navigatingTo">

    <drawer:rad-side-drawer id="sideDrawer">
        <drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>

        <!-- Home page contents -->
        <stack-layout>
            <image src="https://i.imgur.com/LY3cb3A.png" id="logo" tap="" height="100" margin="20 0 0 0" />
            <label text="Welcome to the NativeScript drawer template! This is the home page. Try tapping the logo." margin="20" horizontalAlignment="center" textWrap="true" />
        </stack-layout>

        </drawer:rad-side-drawer.mainContent>
        <drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
            <widgets:drawer-content />
        </drawer:rad-side-drawer.drawerContent>
    </drawer:rad-side-drawer>

    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**main-page.ts**

```
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { MainModel } from "../../models/main-view";

let drawer:any;

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new MainModel();
    drawer = page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
    console.log("navigatingTo");
    console.log(drawer);
}

export function loaded(args: EventData) {
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    drawer = page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
    console.log("Loaded");
    console.log(drawer);
};

export function toggleDrawer() {
    if(drawer) {
        drawer.toggleDrawerState();
    }
}
```

I am really stuck there and would really appreciate the help of some more experienced people on the matter.

NativeScript looks awesome and really looking forward to manage to build something good with it.

Looking forward to read some answers, thanks for reading so far  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) For your Module 'ui/drawer-content' not-loading issue:

You are using **widgets:drawer-content** tag without any reference for this widget.
Instead of loading external widget you can create your custom one.
For example replace the non-refered widget with this:

```
    <StackLayout cssClass="drawerContent">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout cssClass="drawerMenuContent">
            <Label text="Primary" />
            <Label text="Social" />
            <Label text="Promotions" />
            <Label text="Labels" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

2.) As for the issue with undefined id of your drawer you should **remove** the following part of your code in main-page.xml

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And implement your initial page content inside **drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent**  (like you have already done).
The reason : The sidedrawer can not be on the same level with other ui elements in your xml-tree.

```
<drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
     <!-- Home page contents -->
    <StackLayout>
        <Image src="https://i.imgur.com/LY3cb3A.png" id="logo"  />
        <Label text="Welcome to the NativeScript drawer template! Swipe to show drawer!" margin="20"  />
    </StackLayout>
</ drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
```

For additional information about the sidedrawer I recommend the following tutorial [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/SideDrawer/getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

As for the point "1", I actually had the reference in, but deleted some part of the code for brievity while forgetting to remove "widgets:drawer-content" tag in the over file. My bad  :)

I am guessing all is in place but I still got this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined
"/data/data/org.nativescript.githubreader/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.js, line: 17, column: 39

Same as issue:
https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/issues/24

Will try to solve that but so far, no luck